# How can I cast uint8 * to struct that contains array element of variable length? (C Programming)

Tags: c, arrays, memory, dynamic, runtime

I want to parse/cast data which I have a `uint8 * pMyMemoryLocation` to. The data is represented as uint8 in memory but shall be casted/parsed to structs of known composition.

The data shall be parsed to:

```
typedef struct{
 uint8 iNrOfChannels;
 uint8 someValue1;
 uint16 someValue2;
 uint32 someValue3;

 struct{
  uint8 someMoreValue1;
  uint16 someMoreValue2;
  uint32 someMoreValue3;
 }mySecondStructType[iNrOfChannels];

}myFirstStructType
```

I kind of want to cast the uint8 in memory to these structs, which i do like this:

```
 myFirstStructType * pMyFirstStruct = (myStructType *)pMyMemoryLocation;
 pMyMemoryLocation += 8; //Set pointer
```

Now this works fine. The problem is as follows:

```
 mySecondStructType * pMySecondStruct = 
  (mySecondStructType *[iNrOfChannels])pMyMemoryLocation;
```

Gets me:

Error[Pe028]: expression must have a constant value

Now the `iNrOfChannels` can only be obtained during runtime since it is the first member of `pMyFirstStruct`!

I do not want to copy or use further memory, since the data sits at `*pMyMemoryLocation` in the correct order and I do have the information on its composition.

Is there a possibility to cast that array of structs with a dynamic size?

Thanks for help in advance!

EDIT: I am really new to C Programming...

Comment: Note: even the first has undefined behaviour

Comment: Hey! Yes i know... this is kind of hacky I guess... I read about it in another post. Yet I need a way to somehow cast that memory to the type I want to get my data consistent.

Comment: There are no compilers where it is guaranteed to work, x86-64 GCC included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you cannot cast something into a dynamic array.
Once your struct will be correclty initialized, your memory will look like this: 
| 1 byte | 1 byte | 2 bytes | 4 bytes | 8 bytes |  ------> | iNrOfChannels * sizeof (mySecondStructType) bytes|

You have your 4 first variables next to each other, then your pointer.
It will always be of size 8 bytes because it is a pointer, and pointer size never varies. But that pointer points to a random location in your memory that has a sufficient size to contain the array of mySecondStruct.
You need to allocate memory for that pointer, otherwise you won't ever have enough memory for it.

```
pMyFirstStruct->inner_struct = malloc (sizeof (mySecondStructType) * pMyFirstStruct->iNrOfChannels);
```

this way, you have your 2 memory areas, the one composed of 1, 1, 2, 4, 8 bytes that composes your struct, then the one with a dynamic size, somewhere in your memory, pointed by your pointer.

you now just have to make a loop to cast your memory channel by channel into SecondStructType.

I hope I was clear enough ^=^ explaining memory usage / pointers is never easy :3

Comment: Ok i think i get that. Yet I know that the data sits at that location and in that order in this case. I am on an embedded system and the data sits in a buffer which want to parse. Isnt there any possibility to somehow "overwrite" the already existing memory with the data in it with the type information?

Comment: Data IS like this : | 1 byte | 1 byte | 2 bytes | 4 bytes | iNrOfChannels * (| 1 byte | 2 bytes | 4 bytes |)|

Comment: The thing is, even though your data sits in the right order (which would be the case for a statically allocated array) you can't skip the part where you allocate new memory if you don't know the amount of channels at compile time. Because your structure size will never vary. so you are forced to use a pointer.
Although I wonder if there isn't a way to cast the whole array at once, once the malloc has been done. I guess it would be possible, even though I always prefer to split my code as much as possible for eventual post process

Comment: @sunchezz that would be true if iNrOfChannels was known at compile time, which is not the case.
OP placed it there so we knew what variable he wanted to use, not real code I guess.
This **can't be** statically allocated by design

Comment: I did use your solution and got it to work. I had to allocate memory as you said, but now it is working as expected. Thank you!

Comment: You are very welcome ;)
Programming in C is just sooo fun once you get to fully understand memory ^=^

Answer (score 0):

for `myFirstStructType * pMyFirstStruct = (myStructType *)pMyMemoryLocation;`

Assuming that the data is available in `pMyMemoryLocation`,

Most structures will have some padding bytes. You will have to take care of these padding bytes, and therefore any code that you make will be **implementation dependent**